# How to ignore reboot prompt in a ShellScript

Tags: shell

I am trying to create a Shellscript with the following commands.

```
#!/bin/bash    
ipa-client-install --uninstall
/usr/local/sbin/new-clone.sh -i aws -s aws-dev
```

My problem is that the `ipa-client-install --uninstall` command prompts for a reboot at the end with the default value being no.
Here is the output.

> Client uninstall complete. The original nsswitch.conf configuration
>   has been restored.  You may need to restart services or reboot the
>   machine.  Do you want to reboot the machine? [no]:

1. How can I supress the reboot dialog and just accept the default "no"?
2. How can I check to see if ipa-client-install is installed before attempting to remove it?

I am new to Shellscripting, so I am struggling a bit :-)

Please be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linux pipes to take care of the prompt issue. To rpm -q will help you to check if the package is available.
Your final script would be like

```
#!/bin/bash    
if rpm -q ip-client-install
then
echo no | ipa-client-install --uninstall
else 
echo "Package not found"
fi
/usr/local/sbin/new-clone.sh -i aws -s aws-dev
```

Comment: Thank you.I tested on an instance where the ipa-client-install was not installed. And I got the following error.
"IPA client is not configured on this system.
The ipa-client-install command failed."

Does your script check to see ipa-client-install is present?